# CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available and from oauth2client import crypt failure.

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage, gspread

The error is in gspread authentication. Got

### oauth2client.client.CryptoUnavailableError: No crypto library available

I have installed both pyOpenSSL and pycrypto. With the Crypto folder obtained after installation of pycrypto in my app directory.
I dug deeper on why the above error still persists. I found

### from oauth2client import crypt

to be the cause. The following ImportError is being raised.

### ImportError: No encryption library found. Please install either PyOpenSSL, or PyCrypto 2.6 or later

Please help. I earlier(few months ago) got it working by adding the following in my app.yaml. But this time it is not working.

```
libraries:

- name: pycrypto
  version: "latest"

- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

I use mac for development in case you need this to help me out. The thing is gspread used properly work using oauth2client. Today i tried to install google cloud storage client. I might have done something unknowningly during the installation process. After which the gspread authentication keeps failing. I have no clue on what to do next.

But note that the gspread authentication works flawlessly on production. I verified by pulling the production code.

Comment: did you upgrade Python but installed it on a different location?

Comment: No did not upgrade python. My version is 2.7

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by reinstalling pyOpenSSL, cryptography.

But now i got another error.

```
ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl
```

[ImportError: No module named cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32518458/importerror-no-module-named-cryptography-hazmat-bindings-openssl)